# В каком случае употребляется предлог "ДЛЯ"?

Tags: употребление-слов

Подскажите правило, с помощью которого можно переубедить упрямого человека говорить правильно. А именно, вместо "фильтр для масла", говорить "масляный фильтр".

В каком случае употребляется предлог "ДЛЯ"? Или это не критично?

Ещё пример.

Мы же говорим "топливный насос", а не "насос для топлива"
"столовая ложка", а не "ложка для столовой".

Если можно - укажите на правило.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Масляный фильтр  и топливный насос   - это термины,  то есть устойчивые выражения, применяемые в технике. Значение термина указывается в  словаре, например:МАСЛЯНЫЙ,  Техн. Работающий на масле, с помощью масла. М. выключатель. М. насос. М-ая лампа.

Каждый  термин имеет описание:  масляный фильтр  - это   устройство для фильтрации масла (фильтр для масла), топливный насос  - это насос для подачи топлива.

Как мы видим,   предлог "ДЛЯ" определяет целевое назначение предмета, когда составляется описание термина.

Однако, если имеется  такой термин, то желательно использовать именно его. Собственно говоря, термины и существуют  для того, чтобы заменить развернутое словосочетание одним словом.

Comment: Спасибо! То, что нужно!

Answer (score 0):

Можете почитать здесь: http://orfogrammka.ru/OGL02/70091276.html